# CSS cubic-bezier transition causes content below to jump

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) for my transition in an accordion list. The problem is that the content below is 'jumping' as well.

Do you have any ideas how to leave some space below my accordion (ul list).

So when it opens won't move the entire content below ?

Can't explain it better, so I will attach a preview.

[image]

Look at the 'tags' jumping around.
Jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/dzvbtqLa/

Comment: Can you provide a working example of your code (a fiddle, maybe) alongside your very nice picture? That would lead to better answers.

Comment: Here you go something basic http://jsfiddle.net/dzvbtqLa/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-transition: height 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.17,0.67,0.83,0.67) 1s linear;
-moz-transition: height 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.17,0.67,0.83,0.67) 1s linear;
-o-transition: height 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.17,0.67,0.83,0.67) 1s linear;
-ms-transition: height 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.17,0.67,0.83,0.67) 1s linear;
transition: height 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.17,0.67,0.83,0.67) 1s linear;
-webkit-transition: height 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.17,0.67,0.83,0.67);
transition: height 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.17,0.67,0.83,0.67);
```

Comment: This just puts it back to linear transition, my idea is to keep the transition. Just somehow to give it more space bellow so it won't move the content after.

Comment: Oh ok, but your last instance in the bezier is increasing the size of the div, unless you give a minimum height to the parent to keep it in a safe area, the only solution is to change the last instance of the bezier to be less than 1.

Answer (score 0):

please sir try this one:

```
.collapsing {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-transition: height 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.17,0.67,0.83,0.67) 1s linear;
-moz-transition: height 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.17,0.67,0.83,0.67) 1s linear;
-o-transition: height 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.17,0.67,0.83,0.67) 1s linear;
-ms-transition: height 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.17,0.67,0.83,0.67) 1s linear;
transition: height 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.17,0.67,0.83,0.67) 1s linear;
-webkit-transition: height 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.17,0.67,0.83,0.67);
transition: height 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.17,0.67,0.83,0.67);
}
.panel-body
{
    text-align:justify; 

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/dzvbtqLa/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I just ran into this same issue, and I figured out why the jump is occurring.

Basically, this is a pitfall of animating for height or max-height in that your default height / max-height value is larger than the content within the container that's being assigned said height. So what's happening is:

1. Animation Starts
2. Animates to the predefined height level
3. The content area is smaller than the predefined height level, causing it to 'jump' in that it animates first to the predefined height, *then* to the content area
4. Rest of animation cycles

There's really no way around this other than using jQuery, which is really upsetting since it adds a lot of work and effort into trying to control the animation type ( e.g. being forced to use slideUp() + slideDown() vs the control afforded by a cubic bezier animation ).